# how to send an external command to external program in bash?

Tags: bash, command, external

I have an app installed on solaris which have its own specific commands,normally I have run below commands one by one in terminal:

> eaw DDBSC1
>   (then the prompt will change to <)
>   < rldep:Cell=all;

I am looking to a script to put it in bash file and simply run it,
I have tried "expect" but it seems the bash script is getting stocked in "eaw DDBSC1" line and is not executing my second line,
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Use a bash `'here document'`. The commands following << ! will be interpreted by the shell until the following `!end` string.

```
eaw DDBSC1 << !end
rldep:Cell=all;
!end
```

Comment: I receive below error running it:

INVALID ERROR NUMBER

TO FIX: INVALID ERROR NUMBER

Comment: Do you get the same error message when you enter from the command line? If you do then the `eaw` program is complaining about something.

Comment: when I enter from command line, and one by one, everything is right,it seems that eaw application is not getting the next lines and here procedure.

Comment: first I enter eaw DDBSC1 then the prompt changes  to < and I enter rldep:cell=all; and the eaw application is running it properly.
I also tried putting your procedure in bash file and run it in command line as "bash bar.sh" which is giving above mentioned error, I also tried typing your procedure in command line directly which have the same error results as above.

Comment: In the original answer I missed the semi-colon ';' at the end. Amend the script and re-test - does that help?

Comment: no,still the same,the eaw is an application which is connecting to a telecom node and then accepting the commands like rldep,could it be because of authentication procedure that maybe eaw is doing?

Comment: I would try without the here document. Create a file with the text rldep:Cell=all; and run eaw DDBSC1 < Your_File . If it doesn't work (it probably won't), try to use expect

Comment: It may be useful to run truss (or trace) for the command line command and compare it with the shell script invocation. i.e `trace -p <process_id>`.